# Oracle table getting locked when trying to write out a clob

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net, clob

I'm writing out formatted text to a `CLOB` in Oracle table. Eventually as the process runs the table will get locked. When our DBA checks out the connections it appears that I've created multiple locks on the table and there are no other connections from other users. Any ideas on why the code below would eventually create locks on the table? It normally takes a few days of this code running a couple 100 times a day before the lock is created. There appear to be no hanging transactions.

```
public void Update_Html_Out(string key, string shortTitle, string htmlText)
{
    byte[] newvalue = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(htmlText);

    string sql = "UPDATE html_out SET short_title = :short_title, actual_text = :clob WHERE key = :key";

    using (var conn = new OracleConnection(_connectionString))
    using (var cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
        {
            cmd.Transaction = transaction;
            using (var clob = new OracleClob(conn))
            {
                clob.Write(newvalue, 0, newvalue.Length);

                cmd.Parameters.Add("short_title", shortTitle);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("clob", clob);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("key", key);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Need some more details.  Can you post some of your dba's findings?

Comment: I will once I get info from them. I've created a console app that will loop 1000 times doing updates against a new table to see if I can recreate the lock.

Comment: DBA thinks the parameter `session_cached_cursors` needs to be set to a larger value. This could end up not being a code problem. I'll mark my question as answered if that's the case.

Comment: Just look at your code - your `cmd` holds transaction. But you transaction is disposed before `cmd`. Should be opposite. And this `using (var clob = new OracleClob(conn))` not needed when you do `insert/update`. I think, it is needed when you do Stored proc parameters.

Comment: Besides said above, you talking about CLOB while doing BLOB. You not setting parameter data type, which leads to DB trying to match it vs doing exact match

Comment: What in my code is specifying blob instead of clob? I’m new to Oracle so I could be confusing the two. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `byte[] newvalue = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(htmlText);` this is BLOB. CLOB is long text. So, `htmlText` (large string) would be CLOB.

Comment: Whats the update?

Comment: The issue has been resolved by our DBAs and a support team. Looking at their email exchange the issue was that we needed to enable the small_r_row feature for Oracle Text index. I'm not 100% what that means but hopefully it helps shed some light on how this was resolved on our end. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok. Then why would you mark my answer? However, still, look into my answer and rethink. Even if your code works somehow, its because of Oracle ability for implicit conversions.

Comment: I marked it as an answer because even though it ended up not being a code issue you did point out that my code could be disposing of my command before the transaction was complete and disposed of which could have been an issue as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. Note, you need to save CLOB, not BLOB (you said it)

```
public void Update_Html_Out(string key, string shortTitle, string htmlText)
{
    string sql = @"UPDATE html_out SET 
                     short_title = :short_title, 
                     actual_text = :clob 
                   WHERE key = :key";

    using (var conn = new OracleConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
        {
            using (var cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                cmd.Transaction = transaction;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("short_title", OracleDbType.Varchar2, shortTitle, ParameterDirection.Input);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("clob", OracleDbType.Clob, htmlText, ParameterDirection.Input);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("key", OracleDbType.Varchar2, key, ParameterDirection.Input);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```